# How to describe interface method with a type using js docs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, methods, interface, jsdoc

I have the following code:

```
/**
 * @interface an interface for Foo
 */
interface IFoo {
  init: () => void;
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
  public init(): void {}
}
```

I want to describe `init` method with a type like I would for any other param `@param {type} name - description`, but `@param` doesn't seem to be a good thing for the method description and the `@method` can not properly display the type, after trying

```
 * @method {() => void} init - method for initialization
```

I get this kind of description:

[image]

**Is there a proper way for describing interface methods with a type?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit `@` tags and place description in the comment above method or/and interface

```
/**
 * An interface for Foo
 */
interface IFoo {
  /**
   * method for initialization
   */
  init: () => void;
}
```

[image]